# Can a MySQL select query look for specific characters?

Tags: mysql, parsing, select

Sorry for the unclear title, but I'm not sure how else to word it.

I want to use a select statement like this one

```
"Select time, value from temp_table where time between '2012-01-01' and
'2012-02-20 23:59:59' group by time"
```

But I would like to specify that I only want to select rows where the time is on the hour, ie. the time ends in ":00"

I know that in some programming languages use can use something like Right$(string_var, 3) to check the last 3 characters of a string; is there anything like that in MySQL?

Comment: SUBSTR(time, 16)    http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php

Comment: Use date functions, don't parse the dates as strings. That is really kludgy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better yet, actually, there's a function whose sole purpose is to extract the seconds from a time value:

```
SELECT time, value FROM temp_table
WHERE time BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-02-20 23:59:59'
  AND SECOND(time) = 0
GROUP BY time
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: 1. For future explorers, you can also use minute(time) and hour(time)
2. So, this does what I want it to. Is there any way to specify specific characters in specific positions? As in, `return all rows where the SECOND value in the minute place is 0?`
example 
    `00:00:00`
    `00:10:00`
    `00:20:00`
    `00:30:00`
as it is, minute(0) only returns on-the-hour rows
example
    `00:00:00`
    `01:00:00`
    `02:00:00`

Comment: And to add yet another comment, I got what I wanted using substr!

'Select time, value from temp_table where substr(time, 16, 4) = '0:00' between '2012-01-01' and '2012-02-20 23:59:59' group by time'

thanks @hackartist!

Comment: Better solution, if that's what you want: `SECOND(time) = 0 AND MOD(MINUTE(time), 10) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

you can get last 3 chractors from string using this

```
<?php
$time = '2012-02-20 23:59:59';
$length = strlen($time);
$characters = 3;
$start = $length - $characters;
$time = substr($time , $start ,$characters);
echo $time; 
?>
```

Comment: i know man, i just show you that you can get it by using php... maybe you need to use it in your next project.... :-)

Comment: You're missing the point. The question was specifically about how to select rows with a given seconds value, not how to extract it from a string, so your solution is inapplicable to the problem at hand.